# redirect to html page using jsf

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, xhtml

I can't figure out why this code doesn't redirect me correctly to the html page that i want. This is the code that i'm using:

```
String url = "Start.xhtml";
           FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
           try {
                ec.redirect(url);
           }catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }
```

It seems to be redirecting the page, but nothing appears, even though i have something in the html file. How should i put the string of the xhtml file?

THANK YOU for your help

Comment: Try to use "Start.jsf". More info: 1) If code is part of regular action method you can use redirection outcome from `navigation-case` in _faces-config.xml_. 2) Add `getContextPath()` in URL, for example: `ec.redirect(getRequest().getContextPath() + "/login.jsf?" + Constants.PARAM1 + "=" + bean.getValue());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the context root of your application. In most cases it is something like this:

```
String url = "/ApplicationName/faces/Start.jsf";

try {
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext.redirect(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
   // error handling
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this solution :

```
 String url = "Start";
           FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
           try {
                ec.redirect(url);
           }catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Answer (score -2):

While redirecting to another XHTML screen from a bean, use **'.faces'** extension instead of **'.xhtml'** as follows

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("Start.faces?re-direct=true");
```

Hope, this helps some one.

Comment: This totally depends on your configuration. It is even more an exception than a rule in JSF to have a .faces extention.